# How can I set hotkeys?

Tags: shortcut-keys, system-monitor

How can I set the hotkey ctrl+shift+esc like it is in windows, to the system moniter, or any other programs for that matter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `System Settings>Keyboard`
Choose `shortcuts` and `custom shortcut` and press the `+` button
The command to run is `gnome-system-monitor`

After creating the shortcut, click `disabled` then press`ctnl+shift+esc` to set the new accelerator.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked excellently, out of curiosity is there a place with all the commands?

Comment: There's no good list as far as I know.  The other place to set hotkeys, or see what keyboard commands there are is to use the compizconfig settings manager (ccsm; install with apt-get or software manager).  There are a bunch of plugins that you can tweak. To see what the application is that you want to run, look in `/usr/share/applications` for the .desktop file and look at their properties for the command line to run.