# Alienware M14X R4 Eject Button Not Working, Please Help!

Tags: keyboard, dell, eject, alienware, media-buttons

I Have an Alienware M17x R4, it came with Windows 7 on it, when we got a ton of viruses on it we decided to put Ubuntu 14.04 on it,

The problem is: the eject key on the top right of the keyboard doesn't work.

You can see it in this Picture right next to the alien head:

[image]

Things I've tried: Update-manager and checking the BIOS version
(which is A10 and on Dell's website it's A9 so I know I don't have to update that to get it to work)

so I'm kinda stuck, any help is appreciated!

Note: I can eject by opening files and then hitting the eject button right next to the disk or in terminal so that's not the problem, the problem is that the specific button doesn't work.

Thanks,

---

Update: It works when restarting or in BIOS (if that helps at all).

---

It Works! I upgraded to 14.10 and it works now!

Comment: Hi William, could you please remove the answer from your question and add i as own answer? You should include 14.04 to the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Open up a terminal and type `eject` followed by the enter/return key. If this works, then go to [How can I set hotkeys?](https://askubuntu.com/q/182359/371765) Where they are using `gnome-system-monitor`, use eject and instead of Ctrl+Shift+Esc, press your eject key.

Comment: OK so I tried that and it didn't register that I was even pushing a button, so I tried the "Fast Forward" button right next to it and it picked it up and said it was already assigned and what not, in fact it picks up all of them except eject, why won't it pick up the eject button?